# Select Chromecast media route programmatically

Tags: android, chromecast

I want to start chromecast routing automatically and not when the user presses the button. Does anyone know how i can simulate in any way that the user pressed the media route button? I have looked through the different classes and not found anything.

I am aware that this is not how Google intends developers to use it, and my application is only functioning as a proof of concept.

If anyone knows another way to achieve the same thing (The casting starts when the app starts, if the user has enabled it in the options menu) - let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I discovered was that I couldn't make a check for routes in the beginning of the program because the MediaRouter hadn't discovered them yet. (I.e the call to getRoutes returned only the default route...) In my program, it was enough to start a thread that sleeps for three seconds and then calls selects any available route:

```
if(mMediaRouter.getRoutes().size() >= 1) {
   mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getRoutes().get(1));
}
```

If I needed a more persistent solution, I'd do as Ali Naddaf suggested.

Comment: The default route will be the first in the list of routes. So you need to replace `get(1)` with `get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same steps as usual (get a hold of MediaRouter instance, set a selector, register a callback, etc) but then you need to keep a list of discovered routes in your application (as they are discovered by MediaRouter; you will get a call back via onRouteAdded(()). You need to do the bookkeeping as well (via onRouteRemoved() callback). Now that you have a list of routes, you can programmatically decide which one is the one you want to use and again do as usual (same stuff that you would do when you get a callback via onRouteSelected()) except that you need to call MediaRouter.selectRoute(your_selected_route) yourself to tell the framework about it. For the first part, you can take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android).

Comment: You  don't need to do all the bookkeeping if you use `MediaRouter.getRoutes`.